# Efficient iteration in Python without using range

Tags: python, for-loop, math

I am working on problem 45 of [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=45). The prompt is the following:

Triangle, pentagonal, and hexagonal numbers are generated by the following formulae:

T<sub>n</sub>= *n*(*n*+1) / 2

P<sub>n</sub>= *n*(3 *n* − 1) / 2

H<sub>n</sub>= *n*(2 *n* −1)

It can be verified that T<sub>285</sub> = P<sub>165</sub> = H<sub>143</sub> = 40755.

**Find the next triangle number that is also pentagonal and hexagonal.**

I do have a working solution, but I'm having some difficulty with providing an answer that doesn't rely on using some arbitrary value with `range`.

**My current code:**

```
import collections
import time
start_time = time.time()

nums = []

for x in range(56000):
    t, p, h = (x * (x + 1) / 2) , x * (((3 * x) - 1) / 2), (x * ((2 * x) - 1))
    nums.extend([t, p, h])

j = [i for i, count in collections.Counter(nums).items() if count > 2]
pos = j.index(40755)
result = j[pos + 1]
print result
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

**The output:**

> 1533776805
>
> --- 0.197566986084 seconds ---

How can I find the same answer in the same amount of time without using `range`? I want to get the same output but without specifying a number of iterations. I tried using `itertools.count`, but searching the `nums` list for values that match the above criteria takes too long.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RBalasubramanian Just because I had to pass arbitrary values to range until I found the correct answer.

Comment: upon further reflection - i don't understand the question (especially how `itertools.count` did not work)

Comment: There's already good documentation on Project Euler 45 [here](https://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-45-next-triangle-pentagonal-hexagonal-number/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way is to loop through all the indices of the hexagonal numbers, then see of those numbers are also pentagonal numbers. (As @Mbo taught me in a comment, all hexagonal numbers are also triangle numbers, so we can skip that check.) There is no need to try any higher hexagonal numbers. Here is my code for this problem, which uses a `while` loop without any `range`. Ask if you need more explanation of the formulas that compute the index from the triangular or pentagonal number.

```
"""Project Euler #0045 Triangular, pentagonal, and hexagonal

Triangle, pentagonal, and hexagonal numbers are generated by the
following formulae:

Triangle    T(n)=n(n+1)/2   1, 3, 6, 10, 15, ...
Pentagonal  P(n)=n(3n−1)/2  1, 5, 12, 22, 35, ...
Hexagonal   H(n)=n(2n−1)    1, 6, 15, 28, 45, ...

It can be verified that T(285) = P(165) = H(143) = 40755.

Find the next triangle number that is also pentagonal and hexagonal.

ANSWER: T(55385) = P(31977) = H(27693) = 1533776805
"""
from math import sqrt

_1_50 = 1 << 50  # 2**50 == 1,125,899,906,842,624
known_answer_hexagonal = 143

n_hex = known_answer_hexagonal
x = 1
while x <= _1_50:
    n_hex += 1
    x = n_hex * (2 * n_hex - 1)  # we know this is hexagonal

    sqrt_pen = sqrt(1 + 24 * x)
    if not sqrt_pen.is_integer():
        continue
    n_pen = (sqrt_pen + 1) / 6
    if not n_pen.is_integer():
        continue
    sqrt_tri = sqrt(1 + 8 * x)  # all hexagonal numbers are also triangular
    n_tri = (sqrt_tri - 1) / 2

    print('T({}) = P({}) = H({}) = {}'.format(
            int(n_tri), int(n_pen), int(n_hex), int(x)))
    break
```

On my system, this took `0.026999950408935547` seconds, while your code took `0.12299680709838867` seconds which is more than 4 times longer than my code.

Comment: There is no need to check for triangular - every hexagonal is also triangular with index `2*n_hex - 1`

Comment: @MBo: Wow, I did not realize that! I'll improve my code with that in mind. Thanks!